# How do I create a certificate with HP Systems Management Homepage with Windows 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate, hp, certificate-authority

I'd like to get a trusted, or even better a "green bar" certificate from my Windows 2008 R2 CA to work with my Insight manger home page of https://host:2381

I tried importing the file `c:\hp\sslshare\cert.pem` but that seems to be in the wrong format for my AD CA.

How do I complete this pricess?

Answer (score 1):

To create a own SSL Certificate signed by the company CA for HP System Management homepage I use this howto here:

http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/windows/47-replace-the-ssl-certificate-for-hp-system-management-homepage-with-a-ca-generated-one.html